# Get value of version out of project.json

Tags: c#, dnx

In a DNX application, which uses a "project.json" file, is there a way to read the value of the "version" property out of the "project.json" file?

I'm writing a library that writes something to the current HTTP response and I would like to show the version of the application in there.

Any help on how this can be done is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you publish the application the project.json won't be there so you can't read it at runtime. Maybe set the assembly version attribute during build and return this when the application is running?

Comment: This doesn't work in a DNX evnironment I guess. Get Entry Assembly is not recognized. At least not in the DNX Core while my appdoes needs to support it.

Comment: It probably depends on how you do it. Maybe you can use GetExecutingAssembly?

Comment: In a DNX project, there's nothing under the "Assembly." So, no calling assembly, no executing assembly. Is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the version attribute during build (or in any other way) you can do this like that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.2.3")]

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var name = assembly.GetName();

            Console.WriteLine($"{name.Name}: {name.Version}");
        }
    }
}
```

I did it using the new dotnet cli which is replacing dnx but it should work with dnx `dnxcore50` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing a Class Library or an ASP.NET application?

If a class Library, you could copy the version string to a resource file that you read in during run-time to grab the version. It's kind hard to do this sort of thing with class libraries since you don't get the beauty of a Startup and IoC.

If ASP.NET, then just add a version into your appsettings.json configuration (or a custom json file to store settings) and read it in at startup: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Multipe ways of doing this if you are running in a the web application, not a class library. 
First way custom attributes data (should check if attribute is available):

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttributesData()
            .First(x => x.AttributeType.FullName == "System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute")
            .ConstructorArguments[0];
```

Second way

```
        var name = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("Version=") + 8);
        var verion = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(", "));
```